# Uploading file from Windows to connected Linux server in C#

Tags: c#, linux, windows, upload, ip

I need to upload a file to a connected linux machine from Windows in C#.
The machine is connected through USB, but accesible with a local IP adress (10.0.1.1).
I tried to do this, but it says: "Couldn't find network path".

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        File.Copy("C:\Users\Leo\Documents\testfile.txt", @"\\10.0.1.1/home/lejos/programs", true);
        MessageBox.Show("Uploaded successfully.");
    } catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Generally, Windows and Linux don't talk the same language (hence why you can't use Windows filing system, to upload to a Linux filing system), but there are alternatives, such as SSH (secure shell), or SCP (secure copy), or FTP (file transfer protocol).  I suggest looking at nuget packages that contain these terms, and evaluating them based on your requirements.

Comment: @Neil thank you, I will definitely take a look. There is one problem, tho. The linux machine isn't connected to the internet. It's connected through USB and a local IP adress.

Comment: Makes no difference, from your PoV, internet/intranet/extranet are all the same thing, they use TCP/IP to communicate, you just need to find the correct protocol

Comment: @Neil thank you, I will do what you suggetsed